# errno ENOENT with fmemopen and fprintf

Tags: c++, file, printf

I am new to file io operations. I am opening a file buffer stream using fmemopen and writing some content in the file using fprintf. It is throwing "No such file or directory" while writing into the file. Below is the code(similar to the original code. I cannot paste my code here),

```
       int s = 0;
       char *buf = NULL;
       FILE *stream = fmemopen(buf, 1000, "a+");
       if (stream == NULL)
           /*handle the error code*/
       while(some_condition){
       /*writing into the stream*/
       s = fprintf(stream, "%s ", "bla bla bla ");
       if (s == -1){
           printf("failed fprintf with %s\n", strerror(errno));
           break;
       }
       else{
           printf("written %d chars\n", s);
       }
       }
```

O/P:

```
     written 12 chars

     written 12 chars

     written 12 chars

           ...

     failed fprintf with No such file or directory
```

What are the cases for fprintf where it fails with "No such file or directory". 
it is successful when I increased the size of buf to 2000, so I suspect this is due to insufficient memory in the buffer. Why I am seeing "No such file or directory". Am I missing anything?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: One would think that there would be another error when filling up the buffer, but `ENOENT` stands for Error NO ENTry (and can be used for more than just missing files/directories) which *kind* of makes sense, but e.g. `ENOSPC` would probably be better, or `ENOMEM` or even `EFBIG`. This error doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, not even in the [POSIX reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), so it seems all very up to the implementation.